# Electron project transfer

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron

I'm fairly new to Electron development and have a fairly straight forward question. I'm transferring my project to a new computer and apart from the src files(js,html,css, images etc.) should I copy over any other files or should I reinstall everything else on the new computer through terminal? I'm moving from a PC to Mac.

Also, I know I've installed some other libraries through the command line is there a way to check which ones I need to reinstall?

Thanks,

Comment: Reinstall everything. The Windows binaries won't work on MacOS. As far as your project, those details are contained in the `package.json` and `package-lock.json` files.

Comment: thanks for advice!